# Typescript Pick for literal type

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to Pick (or any other solution) from literal type for connection to main Roles interface?

Reason for this, if i in future will change or delete something in Roles, i can see where i need to change/delete it to.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=66&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gGwgZygXigcgIYBMC2AlgHaZQA%20WArshAE5mWYDmVKwmAUJ6JFAIJhC8KsGgYA3lDqIUALix4ipCtVoMoAXx7hog4XFEQA6oWAALAMLmIAYwDW6KFJlJkCgAqEHAHnhuAGkUCEkY1ekwAPi0gA).

```
type Roles = 'admin' | 'user' | 'guest'

// no connection to Roles
type ApiRoute = { roles: 'admin' | 'user' }

// how to?
type ApiRouteWithCheck = { roles: Pick<Roles, 'admin' | 'user'> }
```

Comment: @axiac Reason for this, if i in future will change or delete something in Roles, i can see where i need to change/delete it to.

Comment: Make `Roles` be an `enum`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can either [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) the values you don't want:

```
type ApiRoute = { roles: Exclude<Roles, 'guest'> };
```

or [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) the values you do:

```
type ApiRoute = { roles: Extract<Roles, 'admin' | 'user'> };
```

Comment: it's not practical as i can add some role in future.

Comment: @RTW and you may or may not want that role to be excluded, you'll have to review these anyway

Comment: if i will in future add let's say 'superuser' role, i will be forced to exclude it in many routes, but there no such need for pick. So i hope maybe there is a way

Comment: Should this be type-safe? When using either `Exclude` or `Extract`, I can specify any old garbage after using the literal type and the compiler doesnt complain. For example, this seems totally valid: `Extract<Roles, 'This Doesnt Exist'>`. Not sure if this is expected or a problem on my end

Comment: @devklick that's _valid_, it'll just result in `never` (and with `Exclude` won't remove anything).

Answer (score 1):

Change `Roles` to be an `enum`. This way its name must be used where its values are used.
When you add new values to `Roles` you can use "find in files" (or the "code lens" feature of VSCode) to find out where it is used.

```
enum Roles { admin = 'admin', user = 'user', guest = 'guest' }

type ApiRoutePublic = { roles: Roles }
type ApiRouteAuth = { roles: Roles.admin | Roles.user }
type ApiRouteAdmin = { roles: Roles.admin }
```

Comment: thanks, interesting solution, but sometimes i wan't use Roles type too.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to split it up into different types and export types based on those types, this way if you add new types in the future you just add them to `AllRoles` and if you need to use one of those types you can just import them directly instead of picking/excluding them

```
export type AdminRoles = 'admin' | 'superadmin'
export type UserRoles = 'user'
export type PublicRoles = 'guest'

export type AllRoles = AdminRoles | UserRoles | PublicRoles
export type AuthRoles = Exclude<AllRoles, PublicRoles>
```

Now in the future if you add another type of role you can just add it to `AllRoutes` because we are excluding `PublicRoles`

```
export type AdminRoles = 'admin' | 'superadmin'
export type ModeratorRoles = 'moderator' | 'supermoderator'
export type UserRoles = 'user' | 'superuser'
export type PublicRoles = 'guest'

export type AllRoles = AdminRoles | UserRoles | PublicRoles | ModeratorRoles
export type AuthRoles = Exclude<AllRoles, PublicRoles>
```